# Can you authenticate Facebook Graph entirely from command line with Python?

Tags: python, facebook, oauth

I'm writing a (tabbed) application for Facebook that requires a background process to run on a server and, periodically, upload images to an album on this application's page.

What I'm trying to do is create a script that will:

a) authenticate me with the app
b) upload an image to a specific album

All of this entirely from the command line and completely with the new Graph API.

My problem right now is trying to locate the documentation that will allow me to get a token *without* a pop-up window of sorts.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to authenticate as one user, you can get an access token with the offline_access permission that will last forever and just bake that into the script.

Comment: Offline_access has now been made obsolete, in their API.

Answer (score 0):

Does http://blog.carduner.net/2010/05/26/authenticating-with-facebook-on-the-command-line-using-python/ cover what you need(ed)?